# Check if Obj is in Array then run code if not

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-push

I am trying to check if an object is within an array, I have managed to do this however I am unable to run the code within the blocks. Here is the code snippet:

```
basket.add = function(item) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
        if(item === this.items[i]){
            basket.items[i].count += 1;
        }else{
            basket.items.push(item);  
        };
    };
    basket.print();
};
```

When I run the code without the if statement it works fine apart from the fact it push the obj again. When I check and then push the obj if it is not in the array this code does not work.

Comment: By "unable to run the code within the blocks." do you mean the count is not incrementing, or are you referring to one of the other code blocks?

Comment: Sorry, the count is working. Its the else that is not.

Comment: You shouldn't be using semi-colons to end if blocks and for blocks.

Comment: What data types are `item` and `this.items`, you are using `===` so it checks to see if variables are equal and the same type before returning result. We need more info

Comment: They are both existing objects created with the new constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code loops through `items`, pushing another reference to `item` to the end of the array each time it finds a value in `items` that doesn't match `item`. I don't think this is what you want.

Instead you can use

```
basket.add = function(item) {
    var i = basket.items.indexOf(item);
    if (i == -1) {
        basket.items.push(item);
    }
    else {
        basket.items[i].count += 1;
    }
};
```

For users of IE8 and earlier `.indexOf` won't work, so if that's important you can add [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill).

Comment: well done for for explaining the issue better than me!

Answer (score 1):

You're looping over your `items` trying to determine if the item being added is already in the "basket":

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
    if(item === this.items[i]){
       ....
```

Im guessing you dont want to add the item once for each item in the array already! So move the adding of a new item outside the loop.

Another problem is that you are checking the length of `this.items` but then pushing to `basket.items` - this may be valid but I suspect not.

```
basket.add = function(item) {
    var foundItem = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++){
        if(item === this.items[i]){
            this.items[i].count += 1;
            foundItem = true;
            break;
        }
    };
    if(!foundItem){
         this.items.push(item);
    }
    basket.print();
};
```

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you. Could you explain why it was not working?

Comment: I don't understand why it skipped over pushing it to the array. I will check it now.